# Override Generic.xaml Resource Dictionary resources from another project in same solution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, generic.xaml

I have a solution in which I have a Windows Phone App project and a ClassLibrary that itself has `TemplatedControl.cs` whose default style is referenced in the **ClassLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml** Resource Dictionary.

```
- MySolution
    - WPApp_Project
        - MainPage.xaml/MainPage.xaml.cs
        - App.xaml/App.xaml.cs

    - ClassLibrary_Project
        - Themes
            - Generic.xaml
        - View
            - TemplatedControl.cs
        - ViewModel
            - TemplatedViewModel.cs
            - ViewModelLocator.cs
```

For instance, I defined this in the Generic.xaml file:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Gold"/>
```

How can I, from my WP App, change the value of this `SolidColorBrush` to an extent that it affects every element in my ClassLibrary that uses this Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to do this. Since I have a `TemplatedViewModel.cs` with properties attached to it in my `Generic.xaml` I basically created extra properties for the things I want to change, i.e., if I want to change the color of a TextBlock, I add the following in my `Generic.xaml`:

```
<TextBlock Content="I am a TextBlock" Foreground="{Binding Path=HappyColor}" />
```

And in my WPApp I get an instance of my `TemplatedViewModel.cs` and set it to a new color:

```
TemplatedViewModel viewModel = ViewModelLocator.TemplatedStatic;
viewModel.HappyColor = "#00FF00";
```

Ideally I would like to be able to set properties in a `ResourceDictionary` in XAML, however I wasn't able to. So for the next few days if someone can tell me how to that, I'll mark their reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to just override the x:Key with another value AFTER the generic value is already loaded.  You can do this by dynamically loading a resource files that contains your keys you want to override.

To dynamically load XAML resource dictionaries, you can do something like this:

```
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPF.Common.UI;component/Resources/Dictionaries/ApplicationResourceDictionary.xaml") });
```

Comment: This does not work. The thing is that the Generic.xaml is not directly referenced in my WPApp. If I try to add a MergedResource Dictionary of the Generic.xaml in my App.xaml an exception is thrown.

Comment: Maybe if `DynamicResource` was available it could work.

Comment: @ricochete See Update / Edit.  You can't use the above code to access your MergedDictionaries?  I am using the above fine in a Windows Phone project

Comment: The problem is that the ResourceDictionary I need is in the ClassLibrary project and is the `Generic.xaml` file. I'm not working with two WP projects, but with one WP project and ClassLibrary project that has a `Themes/Generic.xaml` ResourceDictionary. And regarding your change, it still does not work, but thank you for you help. :)